# Critical Elements Of A Story

Tags: style, technique, editing

I've been writing a story and i wanted someone to proofread my story before i actually send it off for further checking. This person is my teacher and he wants me to categorize all my chapters in parts such as introduction,climax etc the kind of the formula he used to teach us back in class. Unfortunately for me I've lost all his notes and i don't want to sound like a goof and ask him for notes he gave me years ago. So can anyone tell me what are the elements that make a story so i may organize my Chapters so i can get to work and send him the book and work on other things related to the book. Thank You in Advance

Comment: There are a lot of different ways of doing this.  If you want to match the one your teacher used, better just bite the bullet and ask him to remind you what categories he wants you to use --he probably won't mind overly much.

Comment: We can't tell you what your teacher wants you to do. Closing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your teacher used [Freytag's pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dramatic_structure), which is something of a standard in analyzing Western literature.  If that isn't it, I think you are going to have to 'fess up to your carelessness, as Chris suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I agree 'freytag's pyramid' is most likely what he's asking for.  The basic layout for this would be: 1:exposition 2:rising action 3:climax 4:falling action 5:dénouement.  See *Writing Drama: A Comprehensive Guide for Playwrights and Scriptwriters* by Yves Lavandier.